# How do I take an average over multiple columns based on conditions in R?

Tags: r, performance, average, mean

```
tconst            averageRating language startYear
1 tt0000001           5.7       en      1894
2 tt0000002           6.0       de      1892
3 tt0000003           6.5       ja      1892
4 tt0000004           6.1       es      1892
5 tt0000007           5.4       de      1894
6 tt0000008           5.4       ja      1894
```

How would I find an average rating for each language for each year? So an average of all the ja for each year? I want to end with a dataframe for each language with two columns, one with all the years and another with the average averageRating for that year (example below)

```
Year Rating
1990   6.0
1991   5.7
1992   6.2
1993   5.5
1994   6.5
1995   6.7
```

The only way I can think of doing it is with three for loops, but that seems hopelessly inefficient, there must be a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

First group by `startYear` and `language`. Then summarise by `mean(averageRating)`, and then `pivot_wider()` to combine the output for all languages:

```r
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(startYear,language) %>% 
             dplyr::summarise(Rating=mean(averageRating)) %>%
             tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = language, values_from = Rating)
> df 
  startYear    de    es    ja    en
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1892   6     6.1   6.5  NA  
2      1894   5.4  NA     5.4   5.7
```

---

Even neater (thanks to @LMc):

```
df %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = startYear, names_from = language, values_from = averageRating, values_fn = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))
  startYear    de    es    ja    en
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1892   6     6.1   6.5  NA  
2      1894   5.4  NA     5.4   5.7
```

---

The data:

```r
df <- data.frame(tconst = c("tt0000001","tt0000002","tt0000003","tt0000004","tt0000007","tt0000008"), averageRating=c(5.7,6.0,6.5,6.1,5.4,5.4),language=c("en","de","ja","es","de","ja"), startYear = c(1894,1892,1892,1892,1894,1894))
```

Comment: You could simplify this to: `df %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = startYear, names_from = language, values_from = averageRating, values_fn = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T))`